# How to calculate end date based on start date and period which is in the sql already?

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the end date in sql. I have to insert into a table whose structure is like

`Subscription_id(auto_increment)|service_id(int)|user_id|start_date|end_date`

Now I get period from another service table which is fixed. The start date is calculated after lots of manipulation but I do have a correct start date and period. I just have this query too

```
INSERT INTO subscription SET user_id = '44', service_id = '2', start_date = '2015-04-13'
```

I always have the `period` and `start date` in the model and just want to calculate the `end date` using both of this. The problem is I calculate the `start` date after many conditions. What would be the best way to get the `end date` within the `mysql query` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scratching my head whats your actual problem is....!

Comment: I have start date and period. start date is in my sql query and period is in the php array which is no problem to fetch. I want to calculate the end date using them both. What would be the easiest way without complicating it?

Comment: So update your question with code too..

Comment: That's the sql query I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use DATE_ADD function:

```
INSERT INTO subscription 
    SET user_id = '44', 
    service_id = '2', 
    start_date = '2015-04-13',
    end_date = DATE_ADD('2015-04-13', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Where 1 DAY should be replaced by the duration you know.

[MySQL DATE_ADD Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html%23function_date-add)

If you are getting your parameters as variables, you could add a stored procedure or simply concat a string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscription 
    SET user_id = '$userID', 
    service_id = '$serviceID', 
    start_date = '$start_date', 
DATE_ADD('$start_date', INTERVAL $period DAY)";
```

Comment: the date comes from a php variable. not hard coded. Can i fetch the same start date in the sql query and then add ?

Comment: Yes. I Can add sample

Comment: @PreetiMaurya hope the sample answered your question

Comment: I am using PHP MVC framework and in the model.. Can't set a variable. I need an example

Comment: @PreetiMaurya you can also use field_name in the `DATE_ADD` function, so: `DATE_ADD( start_date , INTERVAL 1 DAY)` will work as well

Answer (score 1):

Use DATE_ADD function

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

In your case, Assign your start date to a variable, then use it in your query

```
SET @variable1 = <calculated start date>
SET @period = <your period in days>

INSERT INTO subscription SET user_id = '44', service_id = '2', start_date = @variable1, end_Date = DATE_ADD(@variable1,INTERVAL @period DAY)
```

Edit: assign whole query into your query string

```
$sqlQuery = "SET @variable1 = <calculated start date>; SET @period = <your period in days>;
INSERT INTO subscription SET user_id = '44', service_id = '2', start_date = @variable1, end_Date = DATE_ADD(@variable1,INTERVAL @period DAY); "
```

Comment: It is mysql query. It would work. If this solves your issue, mark it as answer.

Comment: I am using this in a PHP MVC model . Can't set the variable .

Comment: assign the whole query to your query string. See the last edit. I've added example.